# d3: Make a static directed graph

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

I'd like to visualize a 20K node dependency graph in d3. Force-directed graphs such as http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292 are too slow to render in the browser for this number of nodes.

Basically I want to represent nodes *containing text* and directed edges from one node to another, and add zooming and panning functionality. How can I go about doing this in d3?

[image: Directed dependency graph]

Answer (score 8):

Here's an alternative which doesn't seem to use force to lay out the nodes - there's no springing, performs well, and has built in upload/download facility.  Its license is MIT/X:

[Interactive tool for creating directed graphs using d3.js](http://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459)

> ### directed-graph-creator
>
> Operation:
>
> - drag/scroll to translate/zoom the graph
> - shift-click on graph to create a node
> - shift-click on a node and then drag to another node to connect them with a directed edge
> - shift-click on a node to change its title
> - click on node or edge and press backspace/delete to delete

[image: github snapshot]

Answer (score 6):

The zoom behaviour (and pan) you would get basically for free through the [zoom behaviour](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Zoom-Behavior). The layout you would have to do yourself though -- the force layout is pretty much the only thing in D3 you can use to lay out a graph of this kind.

Regardless of what you're using, with 20K nodes anything dynamic is going to be pretty slow -- simply rendering all the elements is going to take quite some time during which the browser will seem unresponsive. An alternative you may want to consider is to pre-render the graph using something more suitable for large amounts of data, save the result as an image (or even static SVG) and add a little bit of D3 code on top for zoom/pan.

Comment: Thanks. How do you generate a static directed graph with d3, similar to the one pictured above, without using force layout?

Comment: You have to compute the layout yourself. Once you have the positions of all the nodes, it should be fairly straightforward to draw the graph.

Comment: Do you have any examples I can look at on how to do that?

Comment: Not in D3, but you may want to take a look at [jsviz](https://code.google.com/p/jsviz/).